# What resources should I use to port my .NET application to Mono or Moonlight?

Tags: .net, silverlight, mono, moonlight

I have a few applications that *might* qualify for porting over to a Linux/Mac platform, but first I need to know what baseline of technology is safe for compatibility, what is marginal, and what is unsupported.

Is there a consolidated list somewhere that helps me determine if my app even qualifies?

What other resources should I be aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run MoMA, the Mono Migration Analyzer.  It will tell you what the problems are.

Comment: Does this support Silverlight Apps too?

Comment: @EnduroUSATour: Probably should

Comment: There's no need for MoMA to support Silverlight apps because there aren't any platform-specific things that it supports. Everything that works in Silverlight should work in Moonlight (barring any bugs, of course).